# 'Group by' on indexed TEXT columns not working

Tags: mysql, index, group-by

I'm creating the following table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE group_by_test (
    txt1 TEXT,
    txt2 TEXT,
    txt3 TEXT,
    val INTEGER,
    INDEX (txt1(10), txt2(10))
);
```

I then insert a bunch of rows, and try to `GROUP BY` on two of the text columns. According to `EXPLAIN`, there are no `possible_keys`:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT txt1, txt2, COUNT(*) FROM group_by_test GROUP BY txt1, txt2;

+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra           |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | group_by_test | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    8 |   100.00 | Using temporary |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-----------------+

1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Why is that? Is it not possible to use indexes when grouping on `TEXT` values?

Comment: Did you try using `GROUP BY txt1(10), txt2(10)` ?

Comment: Or `GROUP BY txt1(10), txt2(10), txt1, txt2` if you do want to group by the whole txt values.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ if you use `GROUP BY txt1(10)` it is known as a function in MySQL and it will throw an error something like *ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION dbname.txt1 does not exist*

Comment: Ah, yeah, it should be `GROUP BY LEFT(txt1, 10), LEFT(txt2, 10)`

Comment: Interesting. I had not tried that. `EXPLAIN .... GROUP BY LEFT(txt1, 10), LEFT(txt2, 10)` still gives `possible_keys NULL` however :-/ (adding `, txt1, txt2` to the group by list doesn't respond differently either)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ correct, even with the left part the index isn't used only if the where clause is applied the index is used  `where txt1=something and txt2=something`

Comment: @ErgestBasha, yeah, I just tried that too... I might consider changing unless I find another solution. This is technically out of scope for this question, but the reason I tried adding an index is because I'm getting `Table is full` error for a temp (`/tmp/...`) table file. I figured that perhaps it consumes too much working memory unless I have this index. Could that be the case? Could a properly used index circumvent a `Table is full` error? (I.e. is there any chance changing to `varchar` would help?!) Otherwise I will try to resolve my original issue differently...

Comment: Yeah. Well, I wouldn't put less data into the database... But yeah, changing to `VARCHAR` might be worth a try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is yet another example of why "prefix" indexing is rarely worth declaring.

If those `TEXT` columns can be limited in size and change to `VARCHAR(...)`, then you can avoid the prefixing and simply `GROUP BY txt1, txt2`.

Otherwise, there is no simple solution.  A complex on would involve hashing the strings (eg, via MD5) and grouping by them.  (MariaDB may have a builtin solution along these lines.)

Run this to see if switching to `VARCHAR` might work:

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(txt1)),
       MAX(LENGTH(txt2))
    FROM group_by_test
```

`TEXT` has a limit of 64K *bytes*; and *indexable* `VARCHAR` is limited to 3072 *bytes* or 767 utf8mb4 *characters*.  In other words, if you cannot limit the  two varchars low enough, you still won't be able to create the desired index.

"Table is full" usually means that `tmpdir` is in a disk partition that is too small to hold a copy of the table during `ALTER`.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you. We're working with a few gigs of data and the disk partition (`/var`) has over a TB of free space. So in this particular situation I don't think it's the diskspace. I really like the MD5-sum approach though. Really clever. I might end up doing just that.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir'`

Comment: Thanks, `tmpdir` is `/var/tmp` in my case, which is on the `/var` partition, which I've checked has lots of free space.